# Android Notification do not arrive from market

Tags: java, android, android-studio, notifications, alarmmanager

I've a strange problem.
I've developed an application that use an AlarmManager Service for send Notification.

When I test the application from AndroidStudio the notification arrive but if I download the same version from playstore the notification do not arrive.

This is the code I use for send notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification_lll)
                    .setContentTitle(Globals.Stringhe.APPLICATION_NAME)
                    .setContentText(notiText)
                    .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(notiText));
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    //mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });
    mBuilder.setVibrate(new long[] { 500 , 1000 });
    Notification mNoti = mBuilder.build();
    mNoti.flags = Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;

    notificationManager.notify(idPoi,mNoti);

    try {
        Uri notification_uri = RingtoneManager
                .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(
                getApplicationContext(), notification_uri);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("ECCEZIONE SERVIZIO", e.getMessage());
    }
```

Have you got some Idea?

Tks

Comment: Is GCM involved anywhere?

Comment: Comment and more code is required.

Comment: your code just show notification, not send!